# Querying for date range in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I have some data in a semantic database that looks like the following, where the first column is the ID of an object, and the second column is the last modified date, as xsd:dateTime's.

```
?s                                  ?last_mod_date
http://company.com/custom.xml#obj1, 2016-08-30T08:44:49.000-04:00
http://company.com/custom.xml#obj2, 2016-08-30T17:24:21.000-04:00
http://company.com/custom.xml#obj3, 2016-08-30T09:03:57.000-04:00
http://company.com/custom.xml#obj4, 2016-07-27T03:26:44.000-04:00
http://company.com/custom.xml#obj5, 2016-08-11T03:23:53.000-04:00
http://company.com/custom.xml#obj6, 2016-07-19T03:05:03.000-04:00
```

I'm trying to filter this list of objects down to one item by date; my query input is unfortunately only precise to the minute, so I'm trying to use a date range to find the object, like this:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix cust: <http://company.com/custom.xml#>

SELECT ?s ?date WHERE
{
  ?s cust:last_mod_date ?date.
  BIND("2016-08-30T09:03:00.000-0400"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?minDate).
  BIND("2016-08-30T09:04:00.000-0400"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?maxDate).
  FILTER(?date > ?minDate && ?date < ?maxDate)
}
```

The above query should find `obj3`, but instead it finds nothing. This is with a Sesame semantic database.  Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your datetimes in the SPARQL query are malformed:

```
 BIND("2016-08-30T09:03:00.000-0400"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?minDate).
  BIND("2016-08-30T09:04:00.000-0400"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?maxDate).
```

Should be

```
BIND("2016-08-30T09:03:00.000-04:00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?minDate).
  BIND("2016-08-30T09:04:00.000-04:00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?maxDate).
```

The timezone modifier is the first BIND statements are missing a colon.